# How to disable game synchronisation?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Is this possible? Game synchronisation takes forever and more often than not it fails to connect. I remember in previous generation it was possible to disable game synchronisation but... it doesn't seem like I can find the option in Sun and Moon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you *can* disable it. You need to go to the global link website and log in. From there, go to account settings and scroll to the bottom. Your game sync data should be there and there's a nice little button for canceling it. Just select the game and go through the prompts to put your deletion request in. It should be deleted the next time the server undergoes maintenance (which is on Tuesdays, according to the site)

Comment: Oh, that's indeed nice to know. Thanks for adding this information.

Answer (score 1):

There is sadly no way at the moment to disable the game synchronisation directly in your Pokémon Sun And Moon game. Maybe this option will be added in the future, but at the moment the game doesn't offer any option for this. The game will try to synchronize as soon as you connect to the Internet.

Though you can disable it via the Global Link website. You can refer to Ashura's answer for this matter.